# Preparing stock data for k-means clustering with unique value in column

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have Dhaka stock exchange data combined 359 stocks

[image]

I want to preprocess this for k-means clustering. But non-uniqueness of symbol I can't prepare data.

Comment: What do you mean by "359  stocks"? Is that the number of data points (rows) in the dataframe. According to what I can see from the data, the symbol is the same as all the data points correspond to the same stock (symbol), but on different days.

Comment: 359 different symbol on the column. Total 10,000 observations

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the data points for clustering, you can ignore the `symbol` as well as the `Date` is required.

You can specify the columns (features) by indexing using `iloc[row_index, col_index]`. To make the data usable for K-Means clustering, you can extract the values from the dataframe using `values`. This will extract the values to a numpy array, which can be used for further clustering.

```py
# Sample data
>>> data
        Open  High  Low  Close  Volume
Symbol                                
a          0     0    0      0       0
b         10     1    1      1      10
c         20     2    2      2      20

# Selecting features and extracting values
# '1:' ignores the first column
>>> data.iloc[:, 1:].values
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 10],
       [ 2,  2,  2, 20]])
```

Comment: After clustering how can i determine which cluster contain which symbol

Comment: Clustering is a part of unsupervised learning, so there will not be any target classes. As you have the target classes `symbol` in your data, you can try and map the points in the clusters, to the points in the dataset and use the most frequently occurring symbol to try and classify the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to *pivot* the data to have one row per ticker.

But I doubt it makes much sense to use k-means on this data. If you are serious about results, you'd need an approach that can deal with missing values, series of different length, and that can use the trading volume as weighting instead of an attribute. If you just naively feed your data into k-means, you'll trivially group stocks by trading volume.

First decide your *mathematical* objective function. Make sure it's solving your problem. Then decide how to represent your data such that an algorithm *can* optimize this.